# How to add paths to "vue-cli-service lint"

Tags: vue.js, eslint, vue-cli

I have a Vue CLI project with some extra directories, `api/` and `config/storybook/`, and I'd like to include them when I run `yarn run lint` (which is `vue-cli-service lint`).

Is there a way to add these extra paths to the list that `vue-cli-service` lints? Perhaps something I can add in `vue.config.js`?

I know I can specify paths as extra arguments at the commandline, like:

```
vue-cli-service lint src/**/*.vue src/**/*.js config/**/*.js api/**/*.js
```

...but then I have to also include `src/` and try to include whatever else `vue-cli-service` was already doing. What's the cleanest way to *add* directories?

I tried searching [the source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-eslint/lint.js#L39) for the linter service, but I wasn't able to find where the defaults are defined. I would expect to see `"*.vue"` somewhere in the `cli-plugin-eslint` directory, but I must be looking in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later figured out that the Vue CLI service's linter is best suited lint the Vue parts of the project, and anything else can be linted by eslint itself. Here's how I'm doing it today:

```
vue-cli-service lint --no-fix && eslint --no-fix api config
```